# How to get total seconds elapsed since the beginning of the month?

Tags: javascript

I want to have total seconds elapsed since beginning of current month.

```
var now = new Date();
var dayOne = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var distance = now - dayOne;
var totalSeconds = Math.floor(distance/1000);
```

But in line two, it shows 31th of this month. what is possibly wrong? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for line 2:

```
var dayOne = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: ah, for day.. I thought it should start from 0

Comment: but wait, `getMonth()` doesn't return zero based month value?

Comment: @Blendester for some reason the month is 0 based but the date is 1 based

Comment: `getMonth()` does return a zero based value, but `new Date()` also accepts the month as a zero based value.  Look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 3):

Change Line 2 to

```
var dayOne = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Reason:

Date will accept parameters (Year, Date, Month, Hour, Min, Sec, MilliSecond);

As you provide month as `now.getMonth() + 1`, it will be November in current Senario. But as you gave Date as 0, it will be October 31st as 0th day of November is last date of October.

Comment: @Slai I changed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var dayOne = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

to

```
var dayOne = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```